# Unable to add the contents of one html in another

Tags: html

I would want the contents of a.html in b.html. I would not want to use jQuery or javascript here. is there a way to include the contents

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="import" id="template-file" href="a.html">
</head>
<body>


    aasdadasd
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: That is still using scripting @kurdy . I dont think there is a way to do that without javascript

Comment: Or any other language which is able to actually run code. HTML is just a descriptive language, written to be interpreted, not executed.

Comment: You have to use some server side programming language, if you don't want to use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use php include function.For example in your a.html file you can write a php script.

```
<?php include('b.html');?>
```

For more http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php